# Silverlight application window goes black for a few seconds randomly over RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, silverlight, terminal-services, wpf

We have a silverlight application that is doing something very strange graphically over RDP. I'll get straight to the question that you may be able to answer first (which may even require no knowledge of Silverlight), if you want more information on our particular problem read further on.

The problem only occurs if we RDP to a physical PC. If I try the same Silverlight application on a server remote desktop session (Windows Server 2012 R2) the problem does not occur and the application runs much more smoothly graphically. The remote desktop session to the 2012 R2 server was a bit of an experiment to see if the problem still occurs.

So my question is what could be different in the graphical setup for a remote desktop session to a windows 8.1 PC and a Windows Server 2012 R2? Does an RDP session to a server like this disable some graphics settings? Maybe there is an alternative remote desktop client we could try?

More details......
The users have desktop windows 8.1 PCs that they remote desktop into from home to work on. If they use this application whilst at the PC physically the application runs fine. But over remote desktop the application's entire window will turn black for a few seconds if they switch from another application and back to it.

The application was developed in house so we know there is no difference in the way it runs between the two different remote desktop sessions. And yet one behaves (Windows Server 2012 R2) and the other does not (Windows 8.1 PC).

Things we have tried....

All of the experience settings in the RDP options.

Lowering the Silverlight applications refresh rate.